# Prove that discontinuity set is countable union of closed sets

Tags: real-analysis, functions

For any function $f: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, we can define the $\kappa$-oscillation set as follows: $D_\kappa = \{x \in [a,b]: $osc$_x(f) \geq \kappa \}$, where osc$_x(f) = \lim\limits_{r \rightarrow 0} \mathsf{diam}\,f([x-r,x+r])$. How can I use the fact that $D_\kappa$ is closed in order to prove that the discontinuity set of $f$ is a countable union of closed sets? And after I show that, how would I prove that the set of continuity points is a countable intersection of open sets?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\text{osc}_x(f)\ge 0$ by definition, and $f$ is continuous at $x$ if and only if $\text{osc}_x(f) = 0$. The first fact implies that

$$ [0,1] = \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb N} D_{1/n} \cup \{ x : \text{osc}_x (f) = 0\}$$

while the second tells you that the set of discontinuities of $f$ is

$$\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb N} D_{1/n}. $$

By taking complement, you have

$$\{ x : f\text{ is continuous at }x\} = \bigcap_{n\in \mathbb N}\left( [0,1]\setminus D_{1/n}\right).$$